# How can you validate a string properly?

Tags: python

Currently I have a piece of code that will allow me to check if the name is true or false. However, if I add a space or another letter in the string, it will still count it as correct. So if I change it to johndoe, since it still has the string "John" it will return true.

```
def bouncer():
    myname = ["john"]

    for word in myname:
        if "john" not in myname:
            print(False)
    
        if "john" in myname:
            print(True)

bouncer()
```

Comment: `print("john" == myname)` ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem by changing `myname` to `["johndoe"]`. You need to provide a [mre].

Comment: Did you mean to use `if john not in word`? You never use the variable `word` in the body of your for loop. Also note that `==` will compare strings exactly (character for character). If both operands are strings, then `in` will return `True` if the left operand is a substring of the right operand.

Comment: @salparadise `myname` is a list. Did you mean `"john" == word`?

Comment: @ShaneBishop oh okay, thank you, i meant to use word as characters

Comment: @wjandrea oops, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You are never using the word variable from the for loop, instead you are checking whether the string "john" is exactly contained in the array `mylist`. If you want to to do what you described in your text, the code should be like this:

```py
def compare(name1, name2):
    print(name1 == name2)

compare("john", "john") # prints True
compare("john", "johndoe") # prints False
```

But if you want to check whether the name is exactly contained in a list of names, it should be like this:

```py
def compare(names, name):
    print(name in names)
compare(["anna", "bob", "john"], "john") # prints True
compare(["anna", "bob", "joe"], "john") # prints False
```